# Understanding deleting and deleting relations in greenDao

Tags: android, orm, greendao

First question is, when does greenDao generate a delete function for a entity? And what's the difference between calling the `entity.delete()` and the `session.getEntityDao.delete(entity)`?

Second, if I delete a parent entity with a child that has ToOne relation to the parent, I have to remove the child by myself, don't I? Actually no automatic dependency "cleaning" is done, is that right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`entity.delete()` requires an entity to be "active", `dao.delete(entity)` works for all entities.

There are no cascading deletes in greenDAO, you got to delete entities individually.

Comment: Too bad missing cascade delete

Comment: It's a complex and dangerous thing to do. You might end up deleting things you did not intent to.